# How can I add an existing user to an existing group id (not group name)?

Tags: permissions, users, docker

I want to add an existing user, `foo`, to an existing group, `docker`. The issue is that my machine has two groups with the same name `docker`, one with id 131 and the other 999. I want to add `foo` into the docker 999 group. The following command only adds `foo` into the 131 `docker` group:

```
sudo usermod -aG docker foo
```

How can I add to the `docker` group with id 999 instead?

**Update**: after a further look, I realise that only the `docker` `131` group is listed under `/etc/group`:

```
$ cat /etc/group | grep docker
docker:x:131:Steve,Mark,Emmy,user1,foo
```

I have no idea where the 999 docker comes from, but the following user can run docker without sudo:

```
$ id user1
uid=260800(user1) gid=5000(student) groups=5001(sudoaccess),999(docker),27(sudo),124(sambashare),13010(eestaff),131(docker)
```

while the `foo` user cannot:

```
$ id foo
uid=305800(foo) gid=5000(student) groups=27(sudo),131(docker)
```

Comment: 1. How come you have two groups with the same group name? 2. You can try by making a backup copy of the file `/etc/group`, and then edit (with sudo access) it to add the user to the desired group (after the last colon, or if there is already some user there, write a comma and then add the user.. You should see the pattern in lines for some other groups.

Comment: @sudodus weirdly ```/etc/group``` only has docker 131 group (question updated).

Comment: How do you know that you have a user with the numeric id 999? That numeric id is used for the default user in live systems. And how did you get that number selected for a user id? Have you installed some special program package? Which version of Ubuntu are you running (20.04 LTS or some other version)? And is it a live system or an installed system?

Comment: Maybe  999 was put into that list only in order to make it work for the default user in live systems. What is the output of `grep 131 /etc/group`; Please edit your original question and render the output as `code`

Comment: I see your edits. Does it work now (or after logout/login or reboot) to use docker with the new user 'foo'?

Comment: I see in a comment that you are running 16.04, released April 2016, end of support April 2021, so it is actually time to switch to a supported version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*So this turns out to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)*

1. problem as stated (X) *"How to add existing user to existing group id (not group name)?"*
2. actual problem (Y) *"What should I do if the `/etc/group` and `/etc/gshadow` files disagree about a group's numeric GID?"*

---

## X. How to add existing user to existing group id (not group name)?

It's not explicit in the man page, but `usermod` will accept a numeric GID as an argument for both the `-g` (primary group) and `-G` (secondary groups) options, at least as tested on Ubuntu 18.04.

Ex. given

```
$ groups testuser
testuser : testuser staff

$ getent group ftp
ftp:x:134:
```

then

```
$ sudo usermod -aG 134 testuser

$ groups testuser
testuser : testuser staff ftp
```

## Y. What should I do if the `/etc/group` and `/etc/gshadow` files disagree about a group's numeric GID?

There's a command-line tool for that, provided as part of the `passwd` package:

> ```
> NAME
>        grpck - verify integrity of group files
>
> SYNOPSIS
>        grpck [options] [group [ shadow ]]
>
> DESCRIPTION
>        The grpck command verifies the integrity of the groups information. It
>        checks that all entries in /etc/group and /etc/gshadow have the proper
>        format and contain valid data. The user is prompted to delete entries
>        that are improperly formatted or which have other uncorrectable errors.
>
>        Checks are made to verify that each entry has:
>
>        ·   the correct number of fields
>
>        ·   a unique and valid group name
>
>        ·   a valid group identifier (/etc/group only)
>
>        ·   a valid list of members and administrators
>
>        ·   a corresponding entry in the /etc/gshadow file (respectively
>            /etc/group for the gshadow checks)
> ```

To check for inconsistencies, first run in read-only mode:

```
sudo grpck -r
```

(elevated privileges are required even here because `/etc/gshadow` is only readable by root). Then once you have identified the problem, run again interactively to correct problems:

```
sudo grpck
```

There is analogous utility `pwck` for ensuring consistency between `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow`.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work in my case (Ubuntu 16.04). I think it has something to do with ```999``` docker not in ```/etc/group```. I have updated the question with more info.

Comment: @TuBui It's possible that the GID for group docker is inconsistent between `/etc/group` and `/etc/gshadow` - please run `sudo pwck -r` and add the output to your question

Comment: sorry I meant `sudo grpck -r` of course

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** to answer the title question, please follow @steeldriver post aka. `usermod` works with group ID as well. The solution below is specifically for the problem described in the body of the OP.

Apparently the problem is resolved by editing `/etc/group` and change the docker group id `131` to `999`. After logging out and in again I only have one group of docker left - the `999` group.

```
$ id foo
uid=305800(foo) gid=5000(student) groups=27(sudo),999(docker)
```

I very much hope changing `/etc/group` will not lead to any weird behaviour. The root of the problem is still unknown (the server login is also managed under a LDAP system so perhaps the two interferes each other).

Comment: In future, I'd recommend using `grpck` to do this for you, rather than manually editing the file(s) directly

Comment: +1 for steeldriver's comment and your own fear: changing the group id number of 'docker` to 999 might cause some weird behaviour. - Anyway, you can always reset `/etc/group`, if necessary for some other application, so good luck :-)